# Well vs good when refering to a gerund?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, gerunds

According to [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80834/use-of-good-and-well) stack exchange answer, well is an adjective, and good is an adverb.

My question is which one do you use when referring to a gerund.

For example, which of these is correct:

> I am well at running.
>   I am good at running.

or which of these:

> That was a well run.
>   That was a good run.

Comment: That's not what that answer says.  *Good* is an adjective; *well* is an adverb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it backwards; well is an adverb and good is an adjective.

You would say "I am good at ____" because good is describing you and not your action.

You would say "That was a good ____" because good is describing a noun.