# 'Cheddar goes "good" with burgers?' Can "go" be seen as a verb of the senses?

Tags: verbs, prepositions, adverbs, collocation, north-american-english

I know that the adverb modifies a verb except for in some limited cases such as verbs of the senses or [copula](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/copula).

> "It tastes good.", *not* "It tastes well."
>
> "It looks good.", *not* "It looks well."
>
> "It seems good.", *not* "It seems well."
>
> "It appears good.", *not* "It appears well."

Etc

However, I have noticed that at times it seems that ***go*** can substitute for some verbs of the senses such as in…

> "That color goes good with your complexion." (looks)
>
> "Cheddar cheese goes good with burgers." (tastes)

In spite of [an answer to a similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38343/goes-good-with-or-goes-well-with), I am not satisfied.

I did an [Ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=goes%20well%20with%2Cgoes%20good%20with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgoes%20well%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgoes%20good%20with%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgoes%20well%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgoes%20good%20with%3B%2Cc0), and it appears that "well" is vastly preferred over "good"; however, [Google.Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22goes%20good%20with%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1993,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en) does seem to indicate that “good” has usage with ***go*** when discussing “looks” or “taste”, although it is not often seen in print.

I have searched through 3 pages of the 9th print edition of OALD, and cannot find support for the idea: however…

**Can *Go* substitute for some verbs of the senses, and so take an adjective rather than an adverb?**

Is there some kind of an explanation to describe the (mis)usage, or is just a matter of “correctness”?

Comment: ***Go with sth*** : *This wine goes particularly well with seafood.* https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/go-with-sth

Comment: As for “good” as an adverb Macmillan Dictionary defines good also as an *ADVERB MAINLY AMERICAN SPOKEN* - a way of saying ‘well’ that many people think is not correct - 
*He’s doing pretty good at his new job.* https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/good_3 also https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/good_3

Comment: I’d say that’s just dialectal substitution of _good_ for adverbial _well_. To people like me who do not use _good_ as a flat adverb at all (except in certain fixed expressions of dialect-mimicking origin, like “gotcha real good”), “goes good with” is completely ungrammatical.

Comment: Ngrams often work better with an alternative such as ["goes well with" vs "goes good with"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=goes+well+with%2Cgoes+good+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgoes%20well%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgoes%20good%20with%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgoes%20well%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgoes%20good%20with%3B%2Cc0). As expected, the *well* version is far more common

Comment: @Henry I actually did that, but clicked on Books at the bottom. I have edited to reflect both. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: It is grammatical.  Unschooled speech is grammatical. It is linguistically incorrect to call repeatable speech patterns ungrammatical. However, grammar can be used to explain the difference between "do good" and "taste good". That's the nuance here. And that's why grammarians call it "incorrect".

Comment: If this were just a bit of snobbery (or worse, disparagement of how some minority talks) I’d be posting examples of correct usage in those dialects of English. Since two different English.SX questions about whether “goes good with” is acceptable at all turn up in the first page of search results for it, I think that’s pretty telling.

Comment: It is kind of amusing to compare the search hits for “goes well with” and “goes good with.” People on the first page of hits ask what “goes well with” polenta, lobster, avocado, Earl Grey, ratatouille, braised rabbit, and potato gnocchi. They ask what “goes good with” chili, scallops, meatballs, stuffed peppers and whisky.

Comment: Personally, I'd change "goes good" with "works well", but that's pretty much only because the alliteration makes it flow better with the combination of words. Other people have actual reasons why is should be "well" and not "good" (although I'd probably use "good" informally as well), so I'm not posting this as an answer. And I don't have any resource backing my personal preference.

Comment: @computercarguy That was an astute observation, as I thought personally (but did not say in the Q) that "goes good" could also be seen validated simply for alliteration reasons.

Comment: @Cascabel Conscious use of alliteration is a pretty sophisticated speech stragegy...

Comment: DVing because OP is using bad English to frame his question (or alternately, is stating bad English and asks why that works.  It doesn't work, it's bad English).  If OP's question is something else, that's dreadfully unclear.  I see it's already been through the VTC/unclarity loop, and further edits have been unhelpful, and the crux appears to be that OP won't accept "goes good" is wrong.

Answer (score 53):

sense verbs or sensory verbs are generally intransitive:

They are: look, seem, taste, feel, smell, and sound.

They all can be followed by adjectives.

You **look good**.
He **sounds terrible**.
That **tastes scrumptious**.   [all adjectives]

the **verb go is an action or active verb**. Therefore, it needs **an adverb**:

- This wine goes **well** with that cheese.
- That color goes **badly** with your skin tone.
- That pictures goes **horribly** with this decor. [all adverbs]

So, this question is easily solved.

If someone says, "This wine goes good with that cheese." that marks the speaker as unschooled. I am sorry to say it but that is the way of the world, which I did not invent and which I am not judging by saying that.

[do good and do well](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/good-well/)

[good and well and mistakes](https://www.lawlessenglish.com/english-mistakes/good-vs-well/)

[class pattern](http://www.ello.uos.de/field.php/Sociolinguistics/Classpattern)

This should satisfy the evidence hungry:

> The class pattern is a typical sociolinguistic pattern – a
>   characteristic type of social stratification - it results from the
>   correlation of a particular linguistic variable with the
>   non-linguistic variable of social class, i.e. socioeconomic status
>   (usually in combination with speech style).
>
> A formulation of the class pattern:
>
> **There is a relationship between social class membership (socioeconomic
>   status) and the use of a particular speech variety in the form that:**
>
> **The higher the socio-economic status, the higher is the frequency of
>   using standard forms of speech** (socially accepted and positively
>   valued speech varieties or prestige varieties) and the lower is the
>   frequency of using non-standard forms of speech (non-prestige
>   varieties) in all styles of speech. The lower the socio-economic
>   status, the lower is the frequency of using standard forms of speech
>   (socially accepted and positively valued speech varieties) and the
>   higher is the frequency of using non-standard forms of speech
>   (non-prestige varieties) in all styles of speech.

[bolding mine]

"go good" is non-standard as per the text and grammar cited above, and "go well" is standard.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99517/discussion-on-answer-by-lambie-cheddar-goes-good-with-burgers-can-go-be-s).

Comment: I think this is a correct assessment... for fifty years ago, at least in the US. The transition from using adverb forms to adjective forms in the adverb place has become much more widespread. Sure in newspapers and books the editors make sure it is 'well', but in speech it seems a little weird to use 'well'. Like putting on airs 'ooh... fancy talk'.

Comment: @Mitch In my own speech, I simply would not ever say: This x goes good with some y. And I don't consider that fancy speech at all. But I would probably often change **well** to **nicely**. And in writing of an expository nature, I think it would be something else altogether such as a good match.

Answer (score 26):

My initial response to this question was . . . "Ewwww.  That's just incorrect.  It should be *well*, not *good*."

Then, upon further reflection, I took your premise into account.  Is the word *go* being used as a sensory verb here.

I do not believe it is. Rather I think this is merely informal usage of the word *good*, not the transmogrification of the word *go* into a sensory verb.

Notice that I am not saying *incorrect usage*, but rather [*informal usage*](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/good_3).  Frustrating as it may be, we have to allow for the fact that usage is what defines language.  Much of what we consider correct today was probably informal usage a century (or even a decade) ago.

Comment: The problem I have with "usage is what defines language" is that you then get "egregious" examples: meaning "outstanding", it [egregious] has been used sarcastically with such great frequency that many people have come to believe that it has a negative connotation - quite **literally** the opposite of the actual word itself. If you start allowing words to mean their own antonyms, then the primary purpose of language - that of *communicating meaning* - becomes null and void. While I doubt we will ever, as a culture, revert to "point and grunt"... Well, unfortunately, many people aren't far off.

Comment: @Chronocidal I don't disagree in spirit. But, I'm a pragmatist at heart. *Egregious* has taken on that meaning. And, it is what it is.    There's no Central Committee or College of the English Language who makes the decisions for us. I have thought about this *literally* every day since the OED added the meaning of *figuratively* to their definition of the word *literally*. (Irony intended)

Comment: @Chronocidal - you happen to be on a site called ***English Language and USAGE*** (ELU) . You might start a campaign  to eliminate usage from the site and possible from everyday spoken language.

Comment: @Chronocidal "[egregious] has been used sarcastically with such great frequency that many people have come to believe that it has a negative connotation" Apparently those people include the editors of dictionaries: [Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/egregious), [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/egregious).  Webster describes the positive meaning as 'archaic' and Cambridge doesn't mention it at all.  Where (or when) hast thou lernt English?

Comment: @Chronocidal “Enormous” has gone in the opposite direction: it originally meant *abnormal*. A joke from the 1890s has a parvenu businessman boasting of his “enormous” profits and not even knowing how right he was. Around the same time, it was considered ignorant to use “Hopefully,” or “Thankfully,” as anything other than adverbs meaning full of hope/thanks. It was to be hoped that the modern usage would not catch on, but thankfully it did. Only an ignoramus would use words that mixed Greek and Latin roots, such as *automobile*, *electrocute* or *telephone*.

Comment: The most important part of this answer, I think, is the first sentence. It sounds like ESL, and if that’s not the reaction you want other native speakers to have, say “goes well with” in this context.

Comment: @Davislor Hahaha, a very good list.  I think that the other example you were looking for was I think the other example you were looking for was "television" though (created because the correct Greek form, "telescope", was already in use) - "τῆλε" ("têle") and "φωνή" ("phōnḗ") are both Greek, and "electrum" and "excecutus" are both Latin

Comment: @user067531 Not at all:  It is **mis**usage that I dislike, because it increases ambiguity, and decreases clear communication.

Comment: @Chronocidal - that’s your very personal view, in my opinion it is clear and unambiguous.

Comment: @JimmyJames If 'many people have come to believe that [egregious] has a negative connotation', then by definition it has a negative connotation. It's usually left to dictionary compilers, especially those at OED, to decide on when denotation is the correct label (and when a candidate should be considered a word, for that matter).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The lexicographer compiling the *OED* cheekily put that joke in as an example of “enormous.” That’s where I heard it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I gave my reason. I don't consider the issue to be informal/formal.

Comment: Re "egregious," this word has been used in its negative connotation by Milton and Shakespeare, so the notion that this is a recent change is wrong.

Comment: @barbecue I think the claim was much wronger than that.  It implied that the term currently has a positive connotation but just that 'many people believe' it's meaning is negative.

Answer (score 6):

Due to the nature of how languages work, if enough people use this format (which is most certainly true) then it becomes grammatically acceptable. Sort of how '10 items or less' is equally as grammatically correct as '10 items or fewer.'

Comment: Who said anything about it not being grammatical? It isn't about grammar at all.

Comment: The premise that **10 items or less* is correct is incorrect.  Some people are fine with it, while others are not.  The same is true of *good* as an adverb.

Comment: No matter how many thousands say: If  you would go, ou would see him. It's still non-standard.

Answer (score 4):

The question asked was:

> Can Go substitute for some verbs of the senses, and so take an adjective rather than an adverb?

Sense verbs have several special properties. One of these is that they can take a bare infinitive clause with a subject in the oblique case if a pronoun. For example:

1. I saw him enter the house through the basement window.
2. I heard him tell them the story.

*Go* cannot be substituted there for those, so I wouldn’t say that *go* can ever be a “sense” verb like *see* or *hear*. But certainly there are many scenarios under which *go* can take an adjective as a complement.

Think of food that’s gone bad, for example, or gone putrid or whatnot. Those are adjectives. When *food goes bad*, even though it’s your senses that tell you this is its state, that still doesn’t make *go* a sense verb. (Oddly, I don’t think food can ever go good, only bad.)

The OED provides at least **nine** separate senses or subsenses in which *go* takes an adjective for a complement, but *to go good with* is not a licensed use, nor even a documented one. Here is a sampling of just a few of the OED’s zillions of citatations for some of these senses of *go* than can take an adjective complement:

- a1616 W. Shakespeare Tempest (1623) ɪᴠ. i. 241
  Wit shall not goe vn-rewarded while I am King of this Country.
- 1772 tr. J. A. Dumay Lett. to Mr. Kennicott 185
  The text of the Psalms went equal with your ancient manuscripts.
- 1875 Chem. News 28 May 233/1
  The milk went putrid after thirty-six hours.
- 1884 R. Buchanan Foxglove Manor III. xxxiii. 122
  Her cheeks went scarlet.
- 1889 Sat. Rev. 23 Nov. 589/2
  Marlborough was by no means unlikely to have gone Jacobite after all.
- 1891 Harper's Mag. Oct. 720/2
  Before us lay a sea of fern, gone a russet brown from decay.
- 1893 Sketch 15 Feb. 178/1
  The Government..are going very strong, as the rowing-man says.
- 1914 S. Lewis Our Mr. Wrenn v. 63
  We'll go Dutch.
- 1919 ‘K. Mansfield’ Let. 17 Oct. (1993) III. 29
  My eyes have gone all bloodshot.
- 1943 ‘C. Dickson’ She died Lady xix. 170
  Whatever else you do,..don't go psychoanalytic on me. I can't stand it.
- 1956 Life 2 Apr. 26/3
  The farm region of Center Creek township and the village of Granada..went Republican by 2–1 in 1954.
- 1960 Today 25 June 27
  Many a faithful servant goes completely unrecognised.
- 1961 P. Marshall Soul clap Hands & Sing (1962) 23
  Mr. Watford..felt the tendons which strung him together suddenly go limp.
- 1963 Sat. Evening Post 15 June 4/2
  Don't go too ‘arty’ on us.
- 1966 New Yorker 1 Oct. 183 (advt.)
   Then I write my letter accusing them of going establishment.
- 1969 H. A. Werner Iron Coffins i. 33
  The ocean went high, the wind swept hard.
- 1988 Changing Times Dec. 107
  As much as $4 billion..goes unpaid each year.
- 1996 Minx Nov. 143/3
  He went all James Dean on me.
- 2001 C. Glazebrook Madolescents 54
  I hope she's not going all vegetarian on me.
- 2001 J. Boyle Galloway Street 20
  His voice has gone quiet all of a sudden.
- 2005 Evening Standard (Standard Lite ed.) 31 Aug. 23/3
  His girth suggested he has not gone hungry.
- 2006 Edmonton (Alberta) Jrnl. (Nexis) 20 Jan. a6
  Part of the reason the riding bucked the provincial trend and went Liberal was because of the significant concentration of immigrants.
- 2007 N. J. Smelser Faces of Terrorism iv. 114
  The media themselves do not wish to go unread, unheard, or unwatched.

Comment: '[D]on't go psychoanalytic' would seem to open the floodgates. 'Don't go mere'?

Comment: +1 (From yesterday). However, I'm pretty sure that *a russet brown* and *James Dean* are NPs not adjectives!

Answer (score 3):

You can look at it from three different angles

**The first-**

Go is a Delexical verb, meaning -

de·lex·i·cal

/dēˈleksikəl/

adjective LINGUISTICS

(of a verb) having little or no meaning in its own right, for example **take** in *take a photograph*.

That is, it's a very "phrasy" verb.

here are just a few examples of how **go** is not to be taken literally

- an attempt or try -he had a *go* at the stamp business (though a noun)
- animal sounds - The cow *goes* moo.
- to give access : LEAD That door *goes* to the cellar
- to be in general or on an average cheap, as yachts *go*

examples (dictionary.com / Miriam Webster)

and so on...
and so you could easily see why this verb might clad itself in different meanings.

**The second -**

Go might be considered sometimes as a Stative and or Dynamic verb (as 
all "sense" verbs are). 
Those are verbs that do not describe an action but rather a state (more similar in meaning to an adjective, though in a sentence structure they are the verb. easily noticeable for they can't be said in continuous tenses and they don't take an object(intransitive). as in one of the examples above -
 to give access : LEAD That door *goes* to the cellar.
surely the door makes no such verb as to go, it simply describes the state of the door.
All Stative Verbs belong to a bigger family called linking verbs,such as be,seem..., and therefore can and will be followed by an adjective(complement).

**The third -**

your example might simply be an elliptical sentences that originally used the phrase -
 *go hand in hand with*.

as in "That color goes hand in hand with your complexion." (looks)

**go hand in hand**
Of two things, to accompany one another harmoniously.
thefreedictionary.com

Comment: go is not delexical at all: This color goes with your outfit. go can mean many things. go can mean match. That is one of its lexical meanings. And a verb is either stative or dynamic.

Comment: Go is delexical ->https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/delexical-verbs-have-take-make-give-go-and-do

Comment: dynamic means it's either Stative or Action verb.
All dynamic verbs are stative verbs as well, not all stative verbs are dynamic.

Comment: The British Council's examples there are for: go swimming,go walking, go shopping.

Comment: i didn't say that his example is of the same delexical meaning as in The British Council's example. I merely pointed out that go is delexical, and that delexical verbs are very quirky.

Comment: @Lambie "A verb is either stative or dynamic"? Really???

Comment: @Araucaria Yes, as used in a sentence, a verb is either stative or dynamic. It can't be both **in the same sentence**. https://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/courses/elc/studyzone/410/grammar/stat.htm

Comment: @Lambie That only applies to lexical verbs. It doesn't, for example, apply to *BE* in *There was suddenly a loud bang* or the verb *DO* in *Do please be quiet*.

Comment: @Araucaria Please, Do in "do please be quiet" is an auxiliary. Let's not put everything in the same bag. Here, there is a particular collocation. We are not all over the do map.

Comment: @Lambie And, therefore, as Uhtred intimates, delicalised *go* would not be *active* here.

Comment: @Lambie But you *are* all over the map. That's the point. And your post is categorically wrong in trying to claim that this type of *go* has an active meaning.

Comment: @Araucaria My post is not all over the map. Go means match as in X goes with Y: X matches Y. It is active in that sense. This coat matches your dress. Also, in contrast to: taste good, sound good, etc. It most certainly is not "stative" and delexical is nonsense. go walking or go for a walk are "delexical". But not: "go" + adverb. And go good/go well are in contrast, and this delexical idea is not relevant here. This answer does not answer the question **at all**. delexical is not relevant to the difference between go good/go well.

Comment: @Lambie Are you really sure that you want to say that *matches*  is a dynamic verb?!!! (Think about it)

Comment: @Lambie There is good evidence that *goes* is delexicalsed here, namely that it can be paraphrased with *BE*. *Goes well with* essentially means *is good with*.

Comment: @Araucaria Whatever. But it is irrelevant to the **actual question**. go is match. **M-W: : to be suitable : MATCH
The scarf goes with the coat.**

Answer (score 2):

The sensory verbs you are talking about in your examples are not exactly *intransitive* as stated in other answers, but [*copular*](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/what-is-the-difference-between-a-copula-and-a-transitive-verb)

"Cheddar cheese tastes good" is a copular construction by the criteria described in the link above, because it is taking an adjective and assigning it as a property to the subject.

In you example, if "go" works the same way, as a copula, then we should be able to say "Cheddar cheese goes good", meaning, in some way, "Cheddar cheese *is* good". I don't think I have ever heard this usage.

If we don't accept "Cheddar cheese goes good" as a copular construction, "Cheddar cheese goes good with burgers" must be a different usage. As others have pointed out, "Cheddar cheese goes *well* with burgers" is also correct and has the same meaning. So we should conclude that in "Cheddar cheese goes good with burgers", "goes" is an *intransitive* verb and not a *copula* like the other "sense verbs" in your example, and "good" is actually an adverb. "Good" as an adverb is a real usage, but it is *nonstandard*, as other answers have pointed out.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but did not want to edit the question again and "bump" it. Thanks for your reply. That said, could you possibly edit to show some kind of support from an authoritative source? This site is a _little_  picky about that

Answer (score 1):

## No

Ignoring the incorrect usage of 'good' in your examples, 'go' is not representing a sensory verb, rather it's a term of suitability. The full verb is `to go well`

To say that:

> X goes [good/well] with Y.

Means X suits Y. They complement each other, work well together, or some other matching term. This *can* be sensory, if you are talking about looks or taste, but can also not be sensory. For example:

> Bob and Shirley make a great couple. They balance each other's emotions and make up for each other's shortcomings. They go well together.

The above sentence has nothing to do with sensory perception, but still works.

Comment: In the first two examples, at least, the use of *good* is indeed correct.  Consider: "that dog smells well; she found the drugs in a truckload of manure" and "that dog smells good; she just had a bath."  Tasty food tastes *good.*  Beautiful music sounds *good.*  A person might look *well* if she or he appears to be *healthy,* because in that sense "well" is an adjective.  But a person whose appearance is appealing because she or he is well dressed looks *good.*

Comment: Compl**e**ment.

Comment: @miken32 noted.

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe "go" is being used in your examples as a verb of the senses at all.  The phrase being used is "go with", and it means the same as "pair with", or maybe "match" or "befit".

Understood this way, the phrase "goes good with" does not, uh, go good with standard rules of grammar.

Comment: Anyone care to give a reason for the downvotes?

Comment: Not a dver, in fact I just deleted my own -4dv answer which focused on how "good" is the wrong word. OP's complaint to mine was that it didn't addess his question, i.e. i wasn't telling him anything he didn't already know.  I wasn't able to figure it out either, obviously.

Comment: This answer does not answer the actual question.

Comment: "Can Go substitute for some verbs of the senses, and so take an adjective rather than an adverb?"

There's the question.  I responded as I did because the question was based on a false assumption (i.e. that the verb "go" was being used as a verb of the senses in the examples provided).  I felt that this response was more informative than a simple yes or no would have been.